# Why ajax need a ".html" suffix in my url?

Tags: jquery, html, url, spring-mvc

Actually. I was stuck with my first ajax call from my Jsp to my Spring MVC controller. I get this example from internet, http://maxheapsize.com/2010/07/20/spring-3-mvc-ajax-and-jquery-magic-or-better-simplicity/

Ajax javascript function as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'time.html',
      data: ({name : "me"}),
      success: function(data) {
        $('#time').html(data);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

HTML as:

```
<button id="demo" onclick="doAjax()" title="Button">Get the time!</button>
<div id="time">
</div>
```

and MVC controller as:

```
package com.maxheapsize.springmvc3.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import java.util.Date;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

  @RequestMapping("/hello")
  public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
    return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", "Spring MVC Demo");
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/time", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public @ResponseBody String getTime(@RequestParam String name) {
    String result = "Time for " + name + " is " + new Date().toString();
    return result;
  } 
}
```

From the MVC controller, you can see the request mapping is "/time". normally, if we call the controller from JSP, we only need to call /time to access the controller, but I am not understand, why I have to call 'time.html' from Ajax url: function? What's the different? and why?

Could any one explain to me please!

Comment: The "extension" part in internet is just for convenience. In fact - it doesn't matter if it's `.html` or `.foobar` or `.cidy.long`

Comment: IOW your issue isn't with ajax not accepting it. It's your server-side script that expects it (and even that is by convention. You can setup the server/script to accept whatever you want)

Comment: I am still quite new in ajax developing. I am looking for a good ajax file upload function without form submit. I mean, submit a file from JSP directly to my Spring MVC listener, I tried some method I found from internet, seems no one really works for me.

Comment: Show your web.xml please. Regarding the upload: have a look at http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ (but that's highly subjective and therefore not really a good fit for SO. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @cidy.long Create another question on SO if you have any (although it will likely be closed as off topic).